# Propensity score matching with multiple treatments

Tags: logistic, matching, propensity-scores

Is anyone aware of propensity score matching methods for when there are more than 2 treatment groups? I am working on a project with 4 treatment groups:

1. A
2. B
3. A and B
4. Neither A nor B

Calculating propensity scores using multinomial logistic regression might work, but then I'd get multiple scores for each observation so I'm not sure how I'd match/analyze the matched data.

Comment: Take a look at my answer here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/405019/matching-with-multiple-treatments/405063#405063

Answer (score 4):

It is not hard to do simultaneous covariate adjustment for multiple propensity scores.  I recommend always using the logit propensity scale, and expanding those into restricted cubic splines.  An example paper is Mark et al (1994) Circulation 89:2015-2025 where we analyzed three treatments.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the `mnps` function in the `twang` package, [described in this primer](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/twang/vignettes/mnps.pdf) from the RAND Corporation. The package optimizes the tuning parameters of gradient-boosted tree models (highly flexible, non-linear, regularized) to user-specified sample-balance criteria. Then you can estimate the sample weights based on the optimized model.